# Material-table returns pageNumber=0 every time the page is refreshed

Tags: reactjs, material-table

"    import MaterialTable from 'material-table'

```
 import { StyledContainer } from './index.styles'
 import { getData } from '../../service/service'

 const defaultOptions = {
   search: false,
   searchFieldAlignment: 'right',
   searchAutoFocus: true,
   searchFieldStyleheader styledisableUnderline: true,
   },

   headerStyle: {
      color: 'black',
      backgroundColor: '#E3E6F2',
      fontFamily: 'DM Sans',
      font-size: '10px',
      font-weight: 800,
      border: '1px solid #701d9f',
    },

   rowStyle: {
      fontFamily: 'DM Sans',
      font-size: '16px',
      border: '1px solid #eee',
   },

   cellStyle: {
      border: '1px solid #eee',
      alignItems: 'center',
      textAlign: 'center',
   },

   maxHeight: '500px',
   }

   function Material({ show title, title, columns, baseUrl, options, actions, 
   localization }) {
   return (
       <StyledContainer>
          <MaterialTable
             title={title}
             columns={columns}
             data={(query) =>
              new Promise((resolve) => {
              let url = `${baseUrl}?pageNumber= ${query.page}&searchKeyword= 
               ${query.search}&pageSize= ${query.pageSize}&sortBy=${
      query.orderBy?.field || 'id'
        }&sortDirection=${query.orderDirection || 'desc'}`
        getData(url).then((result) => {
          resolve({
            data: result.data.data,
            page: result.data.pageNumber,
            totalCount: result.data.totalCount,
            publishDate: result.data.publishDate,
          })
        })
      })
    }
    options={{ ...defaultOptions, ...options }}
    actions={actions}
    localization={localization}
    style={{ fontFamily: 'DM Sans', maxHeight: "800px", overflow:"scroll"}}
  />
    </StyledContainer>
  )
  }

 export default Material "
```

- I don't want the page number to be reset when the page is refreshed. I tried to keep the page in state, unfortunately it did not work. we use this table in the whole project, but unfortunately we could not solve this page problem. i can go to other pages, but when i go back to do any operation, it goes to page 0, not to the page i left.*